# when I run my python code it gives "'list' object has no attribute 'lower'" error

Tags: python, list

```
def clean_text (text): 
  '''Text Preprocessing '''

  # Convert words to lower case 
  text = text.lower()

  #Expand contractions
  if True:
    text = text.split()
    new_text= []
    for word in text:
            if word in contractions:
                new_text.append(contractions [word])
            else:
                new_text.append(word)
                text = "".join(new_text)
  
  # Format words and remove unwanted characters
    text = re.sub(r'https?:\/\/[\r\n],"[\r\n]"', '', text, flags=re.MULTILINE) 
    text = re.sub(r'\<a href', ' ', text)
    text = re.sub(r'&amp;', '', text)
    text- re.sub(r'[_"\-;%()|+&=*%.,!?:#$@\[\]/]',' ', text)
    text = re.sub(r'<br />', ' ', text)
    text = re.sub(r'\'', ' ', text)

  #remove stopwords
  if remove_stopwords:
    text = text.split()
    stops = set(stopwords.words ("english"))
    text = [w for w in text if not w in stops]
    text = "" .join(text)

    # Tokenize each word
    text = nltk.WordPunctTokenizer().tokenize(text)
    text = nltk.TreebankWordTokenizer().tokenize(text)
    text = nltk.WordPunctTokenizer().tokenize(text)

    #Lemmatize each token
    lemm = nltk.stem.WordNetLemmatizer()
    text = list(map(lambda word:list(map(lemm.lemmatize, word)), text))

    return text
```

The above code runs without any issue but when I try to use it in below code shows. it gives me the error "**'list' object has no attribute 'lower'**".

```
sentences_train = clean_text (sentences_train) 
sentences_test = clean_text (sentences_test)

X_train = vectorizer.transform(sentences_train) 
x_test = vectorizer.transform(sentences_test)

#The Classifier 
score = classifier.score(x_test, y_test)

print (colored("Model's Performance", "green")) 
print("Accuracy:", score)
```

I have tried some solutions from StackOverflow but yet the error remains. it would be really nice to help me to overcome this issue.

any response will be accepted.

thank you!

Comment: `def clean_text (text)` <- `text` does not receive strings but a list of strings. Try just after your docstring, `print(type(text))`

Comment: `if True:` is always `True` so it's useless, you can remove it.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I can comprehend from your documentation, I believe you are passing list of sentence string `sentences_train` to the `clean_text` while the `clean_text` function takes a `string` as an input. When you provide a list as an input, it throws error in the 5th line because there is no `lower` attribute of a list. You can try something like below to clean all sentences in the list `sentence_train`.

```
sentences_train = list(map(clean_text, sentences_train))
sentences_test = list(map(clean_text, sentences_test))
```

A full copy of the error text would help further debug the issue.

Comment: I  changed it and run it now it gives "name 'contractions' is not defined" therefore, I have tried to import "import contractions" but it gives "No module named 'contractions'" so I try to pip install it but it giving errors.

Comment: I believe the code is using `contractions` dictionary to find some contraction mapping of a word. This dictionary should be present in your code. I am sure you will find this dict if you have referred this code from some article. You should look into that.

Comment: I'm agree with @tanmay2893. You said "The above code runs without any issue" so you have probably defined all variables somewhere in your code.

Answer (score 1):

You can modify your function to process a list of strings:

```
def clean_text(list_of_text): 
    '''Text Preprocessing '''

    for idx, text in enumerate(list_of_text):
        # Convert words to lower case 
            text = text.lower()

        # Expand contractions
        text = text.split()
        new_text= []
        for word in text:
            if word in contractions:
                new_text.append(contractions [word])
            else:
                new_text.append(word)
                text = "".join(new_text)
  
        # Format words and remove unwanted characters
        text = re.sub(r'https?:\/\/[\r\n],"[\r\n]"', '', text, flags=re.MULTILINE) 
        text = re.sub(r'\<a href', ' ', text)
        text = re.sub(r'&amp;', '', text)
        text- re.sub(r'[_"\-;%()|+&=*%.,!?:#$@\[\]/]',' ', text)
        text = re.sub(r'<br />', ' ', text)
        text = re.sub(r'\'', ' ', text)

        # remove stopwords
        if remove_stopwords:
            text = text.split()
            stops = set(stopwords.words ("english"))
            text = [w for w in text if not w in stops]
            text = "" .join(text)

        # Tokenize each word
        text = nltk.WordPunctTokenizer().tokenize(text)
        text = nltk.TreebankWordTokenizer().tokenize(text)
        text = nltk.WordPunctTokenizer().tokenize(text)

        # Lemmatize each token
        lemm = nltk.stem.WordNetLemmatizer()
        text = list(map(lambda word:list(map(lemm.lemmatize, word)), text))

        list_of_text[idx] = text

    return list_of_text
```

Comment: I'm getting an issue saying "argument of type 'module' is not iterable".  what can I do about this?

Comment: I ask you before. What is the output of `print(type(text))`? See my first comment below your question.

Comment: it's a  <class 'list'>

Comment: Which line the exception is raised?

Comment: it point outs sentences_train = clean_text (sentences_train)  and  if word in contractions:

Comment: ----> 1 sentences_train = clean_text (sentences_train)

---> 12             if word in contractions:
     13                 new_text.append(contractions [word])
   
TypeError: argument of type 'module' is not iterable

Answer (score 0):

I presume that `sentences_train` is a list of strings rather than just the single string your function expects, so something like this:

```
sentences_train = [clean_text(x) for x in sentences_train]
```

Would clean each element of the list, which hopefully is a string.